# Remove ctags and add them again in vim

Tags: vim, macvim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am using ctags in vim. For some reason, I opened another file from another repo that also had a tags file. Now, when I look for a definition of a variable/function, it gives me an option to jump to the definition in current directory or the directory form which the other file was opened. It seems it is referencing from both the tag files.

I want to jump to the definition in the file in current directory only.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

`set tags?` will show you what tag files are currently being used. To change the file being used to the `tags` file in the current directory, use `set tags=./tags`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. For some reason, I still keep getting the spurious tag files. I am using MacVim.